# Sum nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array within an array of objects and I want to sum the values within the nested array.

```
[{BenefitType:'401k',
   Beneficiaries: [{Name: 'PersonA', Percentage: 20},
                   {Name: 'PersonB', Percentage: 30},
                   {Name: 'PersonC', Percentage: 50}]
},
 {BenefitType:'IRA',
   Beneficiaries: [{Name: 'PersonA', Percentage: 15},
                   {Name: 'PersonB', Percentage: 45},
                   {Name: 'PersonC', Percentage: 40}]
}];
```

I would like to sum all the percentages by their Benefit Type so that `401k = 100`and `IRA = 100`.

I have the following code, but it gives me a grand total for percentages instead of totals for each benefit type:

```
var myTotal = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < data.benefit_type.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j < data.benefit_type[i].beneficiaries.length; j++) {
        myTotal += parseInt(data.benefit_type[i].beneficiaries[j].percentage); 
        data.benefit_type[i].percent_total = myTotal;

    } 
}
```

What am I missing to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of array object property values in new array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481539/sum-of-array-object-property-values-in-new-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.forEach()` to iterate through all objects and `.reduce()` to sum inner arrays:

```js
let array = [{BenefitType:'401k',
   Beneficiaries: [{Name: 'PersonA', Percentage: 20},
                   {Name: 'PersonB', Percentage: 30},
                   {Name: 'PersonC', Percentage: 50}]
},
 {BenefitType:'IRA',
   Beneficiaries: [{Name: 'PersonA', Percentage: 15},
                   {Name: 'PersonB', Percentage: 45},
                   {Name: 'PersonC', Percentage: 40}]
}];


array.forEach(x => x.TotalPercentage = x.Beneficiaries.reduce((val, cur) => val + cur.Percentage, 0));

console.log(array);
```

EDIT:

To fix your code with double for loop you should set your `myTotal` variable to zero when you leave inner loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.benefit_type.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j < data.benefit_type[i].Beneficiaries.length; j++) {
        myTotal += data.benefit_type[i].Beneficiaries[j].Percentage; 
        data.benefit_type[i].percent_total = myTotal;
    }
    myTotal = 0;
}
```

Comment: Why must you use map and reduce? Why not just reduce?

Comment: @CoryKleiser you're right, I've modified and simplified my answer based on what OP is trying to achieve