# Add new summary row for cols share the same vales of 2 different cols and handle time difference

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, matrix

I have this matrix algorithm:

Input:

```
const input = [
    ['Camry', 'Toyota', 'Jan', 'Nowhere Town', '50'],
    ['Camry', 'Toyota', 'Feb', 'Nowhere Town', '70'],
    ['Camry', 'Toyota', 'Jan', 'Random City', '3000'],
    ['Prius', 'Toyota', 'Jan', 'Nowhere Town', '60'],
    ['Prius', 'Toyota', 'Jan', 'Random Town', '60'],
    ['Prius', 'Toyota', 'Mar', 'Nowhere Town', '50'],
    ['Civic', 'Honda', 'Jan', 'Nowhere Town', '10'],
    ['Civic', 'Honda', 'Feb', 'Nowhere Town', '10'],
    ['Civic', 'Honda', 'Mar', 'Random Town', '10'],
    ['Civic', 'Honda', 'Mar', 'Random Town', '20'],
]
```

Expected output:

```
const output = [
    ['S', 'Camry', 'Toyota', 'Jan', '3050'],
    ['D', 1, 'Camry', 'Nowhere Town', '50'],
    ['D', 2, 'Camry', 'Random City', '3000'],
    ['S', 'Camry1', 'Toyota', 'Feb', '70'],
    ['D', 1, 'Camry1', 'Nowhere Town', '70'],
    ['S', 'Prius', 'Toyota', 'Jan', '120'],
    ['D', 1, 'Prius', 'Nowhere Town', '60'],
    ['D', 2, 'Prius', 'Random Town', '60'],
    ['S', 'Prius1', 'Toyota', 'Mar', '50'],
    ['D', 1, 'Prius1', 'Nowhere Town', '50'],
    ['S', 'Civic', 'Honda', 'Jan', '10'],
    ['D', 1, 'Civic', 'Nowhere Town', '10'],
    ['S', 'Civic1', 'Honda', 'Feb', '10'],
    ['D', 1, 'Civic1', 'Nowhere Town', '10'],
    ['S', 'Civic2', 'Honda', 'Mar', '30'],
    ['D', 1, 'Civic2', 'Random Town', '10'],
    ['D', 2, 'Civic2', 'Random Town', '20'],
]
```

In words: If rows contain the same **Brand**, the same **Make** and the same **Month** add a Summary Row on top with total sales and add listed order for each details row.

Add an extra number string (1, 2, ...) behind the **Make** for both `S` and `D` rows if the **Month** is later than the first **Month** in the table.

This question is similar to my old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845562/array-add-new-summary-row-for-cols-share-the-same-vales-of-2-different-cols/50845796?noredirect=1#comment88761010_50845796) but this one requires extra logic to handle the **Month** difference.

This is the old code I use:

```
const groupReport = arr => {
    const result = [].concat(...arr
        .reduce((m, [brand, make, month, town, amount]) => {
            var key = [brand, make, month].join('|'),
                data = m.get(key) || [['S', brand, make, month, '0']];

            data.push(['D', data.length, brand, town, amount]);
            data[0][4] = (+data[0][4] + +amount).toString();
            return m.set(key, data);
        }, new Map)
        .values()
    )
    return result
}
```

The old code returns this result:

```
const oldOutput = [
    ['S', 'Camry', 'Toyota', 'Jan', '3050'],
    ['D', 1, 'Camry', 'Nowhere Town', '50'],
    ['D', 2, 'Camry', 'Random City', '3000'],
    ['S', 'Camry', 'Toyota', 'Feb', '70'],
    ['D', 1, 'Camry', 'Nowhere Town', '70'],
    ['S', 'Prius', 'Toyota', 'Jan', '120'],
    ['D', 1, 'Prius', 'Nowhere Town', '60'],
    ['D', 2, 'Prius', 'Random Town', '60'],
    ['S', 'Prius', 'Toyota', 'Mar', '50'],
    ['D', 1, 'Prius', 'Nowhere Town', '50'],
    ['S', 'Civic', 'Honda', 'Jan', '10'],
    ['D', 1, 'Civic', 'Nowhere Town', '10'],
    ['S', 'Civic', 'Honda', 'Feb', '10'],
    ['D', 1, 'Civic', 'Nowhere Town', '10'],
    ['S', 'Civic', 'Honda', 'Mar', '30'],
    ['D', 1, 'Civic', 'Random Town', '10'],
    ['D', 2, 'Civic', 'Random Town', '20'],
]
```

How can I improve the old code to handle the new logic, or is there a new approach I can take?

Comment: What specifically are you unsure about with the code that your have? A good place to start to debug something like this is to take your time and go through the code line by line. Sorry that this doesn't solve your issue, but it feels like you're just asking for someone to do the work for you, instead of asking for help with something specific

Comment: It's a pity that you feel that way.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore was giving some constructive advice, Viet - please try to respond to criticism gracefully. Advice on debugging can be helpful, too, since it may stimulate some techniques or approaches you can use to help yourself when encountering a problem in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pair of questions nicely shows how the "expected input -> output" kind of questions that return fancy oneliners from people that like code puzzles (*I'm guilty of this myself*) are often not that constructive... Whenever a requirement changes, it's hard to figure out what's going on!

---

I'll try to explain what you can do to create a program that will last:

### Your two row types

Start out by defining what a header is, what a row is, and *what information you need to construct them*:

```
const header = (model, make, month, monthIndex, totalCost) =>
  ["D", model + (monthIndex || ""), make, month, totalCost + ""];

const row = (model, make, month, monthIndex, carIndex, cost) =>
  ["S", carIndex + 1, model + (monthIndex || ""), make, month, cost];
```

### Grouping in to sections

Now, we need to *group* our cars by `model`, `make` and `month` to get to the right amount of headers and their required information. We'll use a `groupBy` utility that you can reuse throughout your code and is not specific to this program. The basics:

- Input:

  - A function that returns a `string` for an element: `a -> string`
  - A list of elements `[a]`
- Output:

  - An object with elements grouped by their string keys: `{ key: [a] }`

Many libraries implement a `groupBy`, but you can also define one yourself.

### A nested table

Now that we have a `groupBy` we can create a tree out of your rows, which looks like this:

```
const tableTree = { "Camry": { "Toyota": { "Jan": [ /* car rows */ ] } } };
```

You can write a converter for this data structure by reducing the object's entries, and it should become a bit more clear what the logic is and how to change it.

### Flattening the nested table

You can loop over this tree like so:

```
Object.values(tableTree)
  .forEach(models => Object.values(models)
    .forEach(months => Object.values(months)
      .forEach(cars => { /* create rows */ }))
    )
  );
```

### Running example:

Putting it all together:

```js
const { map, groupBy, elAt, prop, sum } = utils();

// APP
// Properties:
const getModel = prop(0);
const getMake = prop(1);
const getMonth = prop(2);
const getCost = prop(4);

// Groupers:
const groupByModel = groupBy(getModel);
const groupByMake = groupBy(getMake);
const groupByMonth = groupBy(getMonth);


// Leveled grouper:
const makeTable = carInput => 
  map (map (groupByMonth)) 
      (map (groupByMake) 
           (groupByModel(carInput)));

// Get to the cars and make Sections
const flattenTable = table => {
  const rows = [];
  
  Object.values(table)
    .forEach(models => Object.values(models)
      .forEach(months => Object.values(months)
        .forEach((cars, mNr) => 
          rows.push(...Section(cars, mNr))
      )
    )
  );
          
  return rows;
};

// Row types (these will be so much nicer is you use objects...):
const Header = (model, make, month, totalCost, mNr) => 
  ["D", model + (mNr || ""), make, month, totalCost + ""];
  
const Row = mNr => (car, cNr) =>
  ["S", cNr + 1, getModel(car) + (mNr || ""), getMake(car), getMonth(car), getCost(car)];

const Section = (cars, mNr) => {
  const [c] = cars;
  const tCost = cars.map(getCost).reduce(sum);
  return [
    Header(getModel(c), getMake(c), getMonth(c), tCost, mNr),
    ...cars.map(Row(mNr))
  ];
};


// Test data:
const input = [
    ['Camry', 'Toyota', 'Jan', 'Nowhere Town', '50'],
    ['Camry', 'Toyota', 'Feb', 'Nowhere Town', '70'],
    ['Camry', 'Toyota', 'Jan', 'Random City', '3000'],
    ['Prius', 'Toyota', 'Jan', 'Nowhere Town', '60'],
    ['Prius', 'Toyota', 'Jan', 'Random Town', '60'],
    ['Prius', 'Toyota', 'Mar', 'Nowhere Town', '50'],
    ['Civic', 'Honda', 'Jan', 'Nowhere Town', '10'],
    ['Civic', 'Honda', 'Feb', 'Nowhere Town', '10'],
    ['Civic', 'Honda', 'Mar', 'Random Town', '10'],
    ['Civic', 'Honda', 'Mar', 'Random Town', '20'],
];


// Run App:
console.log(
  flattenTable(makeTable(input))
    .map(row => `[${row.join(", ")}]`));


function utils() { 
  return {
    groupBy: getKey => xs => xs
      .map(x => [getKey(x), x])
      .reduce(
        (gs, [k, x]) => Object.assign(
          gs, 
          { [k]: (gs[k] || []).concat([x]) }
        ),
        {}
      ),
    map: f => obj => Object.entries(obj)
      .reduce(
        (o, [k, v]) => Object.assign(o, { [k]: f(v) }),
        {}
      ),
    prop: k => o => o[k],
    sum: (x, y) => +x + +y
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much @user3297291 for your understanding and for not criticising me. 
Yes, you're absolutely right. You've said it all. My original plan was to create reusable functions to convert the massive data I have to deal with.
I was able to convert some with a few matrix algorithms then I hit the wall. That's when I asked for help here, and you know the rest.
I really appreciate the people on this website who spend their time trying to help people like me.

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate a lookup hash and then loop through until you reach month data and generate required output (ideally recursively, but I did it iteratively):

```
var input = [
    ['Camry', 'Toyota', 'Jan', 'Nowhere Town', '50'],
    ['Camry', 'Toyota', 'Feb', 'Nowhere Town', '70'],
    ['Camry', 'Toyota', 'Jan', 'Random City', '3000'],
    ['Prius', 'Toyota', 'Jan', 'Nowhere Town', '60'],
    ['Prius', 'Toyota', 'Jan', 'Random Town', '60'],
    ['Prius', 'Toyota', 'Mar', 'Nowhere Town', '50'],
    ['Civic', 'Honda', 'Jan', 'Nowhere Town', '10'],
    ['Civic', 'Honda', 'Feb', 'Nowhere Town', '10'],
    ['Civic', 'Honda', 'Mar', 'Random Town', '10'],
    ['Civic', 'Honda', 'Mar', 'Random Town', '20'],
]

var dataObj = input.reduce((all, [brand, make, month, city, count]) => {

    if (!all.hasOwnProperty(brand)) all[brand] = {};

    if (!all[brand].hasOwnProperty(make)) all[brand][make] = {};

    if (!all[brand][make].hasOwnProperty(month)) all[brand][make][month] = [];

    all[brand][make][month].push({city, count});

    return all;

}, {});


var result = Object.keys(dataObj).reduce((all, brand) => {

    Object.keys(dataObj[brand]).forEach(make => {

        Object.keys(dataObj[brand][make]).forEach((month, j) => {

            const id = j || '';

            dataObj[brand][make][month]
                .reduce((final, {city, count}, i) => {

                    final[0][4] += Number(count);
                    final.push(['D', i + 1, `${brand}${id}`, make, month, count]);
                    return final;

                },[['S', `${brand}${id}`, make, month, 0]])
                .forEach(item => all.push(item));

        });

    });

    return all;

}, []);

console.log(result);
```