# JS Array with arrays of objects - Group and sum properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this one array with multiple arrays in it, containing objects (responses from HTTP requests)

The big array:

```
datas = [
   [
     {
       data: {
         pid: 107,
         value: 5
       }
       status: 200
     },
     {
       data: {
          pid: 108,
          value: 42
       }
     }
   ],
   [
     {
       data: {
         pid: 107,
         value: 64
       }
       status: 200
     },
     {
       data: {
          pid: 108,
          value: 322
       }
     }
   ]
]
```

Ok, so how could I make a new array (or object) grouped by pid and a sum with values assigned to pid? **It is not the typical question with a SUM by property inside array of arrays.**

What I have tried:

```
 datas.forEach((d,k1) => { 
   d.forEach((e,k2) => {
   total += e.data.value
   newArr[k2] = total;
  })
})
```

Comment: It is well received to always include what you have tried so far...

Comment: You should also show what output you expect. Note that there are many questions with similar titles; you'll want to say how yours differs. For example, [Sum of array object property values in new array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37481539/215552)

Comment: It is not a just the typical question - make the sum of a property in an array. C'mmon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce` with an inner `Array.prototype.forEach` to iterate over the inner arrays and group PIDs into an `Object`:

```js
const data = [
   [
     {
       data: {
         pid: 107,
         value: 5
       },
       status: 200
     },
     {
       data: {
          pid: 108,
          value: 42
       }
     }
   ],
   [
     {
       data: {
         pid: 107,
         value: 64
       },
       status: 200
     },
     {
       data: {
          pid: 108,
          value: 322
       }
     }
   ]
];

const merged = data.reduce((merged, innerArr) => {
  innerArr.forEach(({data}) => {
    merged[data.pid] = (merged[data.pid] || 0) + data.value;
  });
  return merged;
}, {});

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: Finally.  I didn't know how to use the reducer function with objects in the array. Thank you very much.