# How to get the sum of number from an array of objects, using pure JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to show the **total number of Likes** using only pure JS.
I grabbed the numbers from the JSON file but I don't know how to get the Total number of likes,
I tried to use **reduce** method it didn't work maybe i am doing in the wron way

This is what I want to do [click here for the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyYDt.jpg)
This is my code

```
function photographerWork(JsonData, homeElement){
   const homeElt = homeElement.id;
   JsonData.media.forEach(element => {   
   if(homeElt == element.photographerId){
       const domDiv = document.getElementById('photographer-work');
       const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
       /////  the code i'am trying  ////
       const allTheLiks = element.likes
       console.log(allTheLiks)
       //////////////////////
       const workTemplate = `         
           <div class="photo-box"> 
               <div class="photo">
                   ${videoOrImage(element.image, element.video, element)}
               </div>   
               <div class="text">
                   <p> ${element.tags}<b>${element.price} €  &nbsp ${element.likes} <i class="fas fa-heart"></i></b></p>
               </div>
           </div>
           `
       newDiv.innerHTML = workTemplate;
       domDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
       likesAndPrice(element, allTheLiks); 
     }
 })
}
```

This is my Result [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooDrJ.jpg)`enter code here`

This is my JSON file example

```
 "media": [
      {
        "id": 342550,
        "photographerId": 82,
        "image": "../Photos/Tracy/Fashion_Yellow_Beach.jpg",
        "tags": ["fashion"],
        "likes": 62,
        "date": "2011-12-08",
        "price": 55
      },
      {
        "id": 8520927,
        "photographerId": 82,
        "image": "../Photos/Tracy/Fashion_Urban_Jungle.jpg",
        "tags": ["fashion"],
        "likes": 11,
        "date": "2011-11-06",
        "price": 55
      },
      {
        "id": 9025895,
        "photographerId": 82,
        "image": "../Photos/Tracy/Fashion_Pattern_on_Pattern.jpg",
        "tags": ["fashion"],
        "likes": 72,
        "date": "2013-08-12",
        "price": 55
      },
      {
        "id": 9275938,
        "photographerId": 82,
        "image": "../Photos/Tracy/Event_WeddingGazebo.jpg",
        "tags": ["events"],
        "likes": 69,
        "date": "2018-02-22",
        "price": 55
      },
      {
        "id": 2053494,
        "photographerId": 82,
        "image": "../Photos/Tracy/Event_Sparklers.jpg",
        "tags": ["events"],
        "likes": 2,
        "date": "2020-05-25",
        "price": 55
      },
```

Comment: sum them up in the loop

Comment: Hi! @EgzonBerisha I have something going on. I will add the answer soon. But just to confirm what is the reduce formulation you have done till now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of array object property values in new array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481539/sum-of-array-object-property-values-in-new-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: NOTE TO POTENTIAL ANSWERERS: This question, and questions like it, are asked with relatively high frequency on Stack Overflow. So often does this happen, we have several canonical duplicates. Please at least do a cursory search for duplicate before answering the question.

Comment: @EgzonBerisha I have offered a one liner answer to the problem - took me hours to figure. hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Before* you enter the `forEach()` create a local variable sum

```
let sum = 0;
```

Then *inside* your `forEach()` do the following

```
sum += element.likes;
```

Then when the loop has finished in sum will be the total amount of likes.

Updated code.

```
function photographerWork(JsonData, homeElement){
   let sum = 0;
   const homeElt = homeElement.id;
   JsonData.media.forEach(element => {   
   if(homeElt == element.photographerId){
       const domDiv = document.getElementById('photographer-work');
       const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
       /////  the code i'am trying  ////
       const allTheLiks = element.likes
       console.log(allTheLiks)
       //////////////////////

       sum += element.price;

       const workTemplate = `         
           <div class="photo-box"> 
               <div class="photo">
                   ${videoOrImage(element.image, element.video, element)}
               </div>   
               <div class="text">
                   <p> ${element.tags}<b>${element.price} €  &nbsp ${element.likes} <i class="fas fa-heart"></i></b></p>
               </div>
           </div>
           `
       newDiv.innerHTML = workTemplate;
       domDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
       likesAndPrice(element, allTheLiks); 
     }

})
 // here you have the sum now 
    console.log(sum);
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you very much this actually worked, my problem was not knowing where to position elements inside the loop or outside, thank you man, is it possible to use the result inside a template literale in another function ?

Comment: You're welcome @EgzonBerisha :)

Sure you can pass it as a parameter to another function and there you can most likely use it as template literale. *Not familiar with template literale*
where the console log is you can call your function with sum as parameter
`yourfunction(sum)`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const media = [{
    "id": 342550,
    "photographerId": 82,
    "image": "../Photos/Tracy/Fashion_Yellow_Beach.jpg",
    "tags": ["fashion"],
    "likes": 62,
    "date": "2011-12-08",
    "price": 55
  },
  {
    "id": 8520927,
    "photographerId": 82,
    "image": "../Photos/Tracy/Fashion_Urban_Jungle.jpg",
    "tags": ["fashion"],
    "likes": 11,
    "date": "2011-11-06",
    "price": 55
  },
  {
    "id": 9025895,
    "photographerId": 82,
    "image": "../Photos/Tracy/Fashion_Pattern_on_Pattern.jpg",
    "tags": ["fashion"],
    "likes": 72,
    "date": "2013-08-12",
    "price": 55
  },
  {
    "id": 9275938,
    "photographerId": 82,
    "image": "../Photos/Tracy/Event_WeddingGazebo.jpg",
    "tags": ["events"],
    "likes": 69,
    "date": "2018-02-22",
    "price": 55
  },
  {
    "id": 2053494,
    "photographerId": 82,
    "image": "../Photos/Tracy/Event_Sparklers.jpg",
    "tags": ["events"],
    "likes": 2,
    "date": "2020-05-25",
    "price": 55
  }
];

const response = media.reduce((total, { likes }) => {
  total += likes;
  return total;
}, 0);

console.log(`total likes: ${response}`);
```

you can use `reduce` function and do something like that:

```
const response = media.reduce((total, { likes }) => {
  total += likes;
  return total;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `jsonData` to be the variable holding your data.

```
var totalLikes =  jsonData.media.reduce((acc, cur) => (true, {likes: acc.likes + cur.likes})).likes
```

A great one liner to do the task. There are two ways - one that @Kidas has posted and mine - which just reduces in such a way that a JSON object is maintained throughout the reduce and the later accessing that. If you don't like to use the ES6 syntax - just replace the arrow function with a `function`

```
var totalLikes =  jsonData.media.reduce(function (acc, cur) {
    return (true, {likes: acc.likes + cur.likes})
}).likes
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the likes eachtime you render a card(i.e: object). I have added a variable `combinedLikes` and adding the likes each time.

cheers :)

```
function photographerWork(JsonData, homeElement){
   const homeElt = homeElement.id;
   let combinedLikes = 0;
   JsonData.media.forEach(element => {   
   if(homeElt == element.photographerId){
       const domDiv = document.getElementById('photographer-work');
       const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
       /////  the code i'am trying  ////
       combinedLikes += element.likes;
       console.log(allTheLiks)
       //////////////////////
       const workTemplate = `         
           <div class="photo-box"> 
               <div class="photo">
                   ${videoOrImage(element.image, element.video, element)}
               </div>   
               <div class="text">
                   <p> ${element.tags}<b>${element.price} €  &nbsp ${element.likes} <i class="fas fa-heart"></i></b></p>
               </div>
           </div>
           `
       newDiv.innerHTML = workTemplate;
       domDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
       likesAndPrice(element, combinedLikes); 
     }
 })
}
```